# just fill specific entrys of numpy array -> generating sparse matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to code a really big matrix with the following structure:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Dimension of this array is (3,9) so basically the 1's depend on the dimension.
In my first row the first 3 entrys should be 1's, in my second row the entrys 3-5 should be 1's,
and so on...

How do I code this?

Comment: `x,y = np.where(a)` ?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean with this...can you explain?

Comment: Hooo ok I get what you want, but you should edit your title, this is not a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [kronecker tensor product](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html):

```
a = np.kron(np.eye(3),np.ones((1,3)))

# array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```